# search with sum based on date without writing in sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search

I'm trying to create a search button where it cycles through the range (B) of data. If the date is the same as the search, vba must sum the Range (E) values ​​if the Range (D) is equal.
Example:

| Column B | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/04/2023 | GOLD | 5 |
| 10/04/2023 | SILVER | 4 |
| 09/03/2023 | KOLITA | 7 |
| 11/04/2023 | GOLD | 3 |

In the search, if I want to know the values ​​of month 04, the return should be:
GOLD: 8, SILVER: 4

Which way should I go to do this, since I don't want to write in the sheet, since I use a database and I don't want to open it to do the research?

im tried to use array, but i don't know if it's the right way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly ....

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, rgU As Range, dt As Date
Dim arr: Dim el: Dim c As Range: Dim oSum as Integer

'set the range of date in column B - change if needed
With Sheet3
Set rg = .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

'date input
dt = "1-apr-23"

Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each cell In rg
If Format(dt, "mmm-yy") = Format(cell.Value, "mmm-yy") Then
    If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = cell Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, cell)
    arr.Item(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value) = 1
End If
Next

For Each el In arr
oSum = 0
    With rgU.Offset(0, 2)
        Set c = .Find(el)
        fa = c.Address
            Do
                If Not c Is Nothing Then oSum = oSum + c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop Until c.Address = fa
    End With
MsgBox el & " : " & oSum
Next

End Sub
```

it set the rg as the range of date in column D.
the input as dt variable must be a date, complete with date, month and year.

Then it loop to each cell, and compare if the dt formatted as "mmm-yy" is the same with the looped cell formatted as "mmm-yy". If it's the same then it collect the looped cell into rgU variable, and create a unique item based on the looped cell.offset(0,2).

When that loop done, arr has a unique value from column D which is inside rgU.offset(0,2). So then it loop to each el in arr to get the sum of the el using the find/findnext method within the rgU.offset(0,2).

Comment: Ty sir! works perfectly. I need to do a little adaptation but that's exactly what I needed